# How does scripted Jenkins Pipeline with Groovy work

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```
stage('deploy') {
    steps {
        script {

            import java.net.URL;
            import java.net.URLConnection;

            def serviceURL = ""

            if (env.BRANCH_NAME == "master") {

                serviceURL="http://myserver:8100/jira/rest/plugins/1.0"
            }
            if (env.BRANCH_NAME == "develop") {

                serviceURL = "http://myserver:8100/jira/rest/plugins/1.0"
            }
            if(env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith("release")
            {
                serviceURL="http://myserver:8100/jira/rest/plugins/1.0"
            }

            // Request to get token
            URL myURL = new URL(serviceURL+"?"+"os_authType=basic");
            HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)myURL.openConnection();
  }
```

This is an extract of my jenkinsfile. It is written in Groovy .
Right now I get this error:

```
WorkflowScript: 66: expecting ')', found 'URL' @ line 66, column 17.
```

It is complaining about this line:

```
URL myURL = new URL(serviceURL+"?"+"os_authType=basic");
```

I do not know why. But one thing I was wondering now.
How does it actually work with imports. I mean normally you have to do

```
 import java.net.URL
```

How would it actually work with extern libraries which are not part of Java SDK.
Normally you would put them on the classpath. How would that work with jenkinsfile scripted pipeline. So I wonder when you can actually use jenkinsfile with groovy or when to better
create an own project and  create job for it and then add it in the jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to import `java.net.*`, groovy imports them by default. https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_default_imports.

Your problem is a result of a missing `)` in the line:

```
if(env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith("release")
```

it should be

```
if(env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith("release"))
```

The whole script should look like so in idiomatic Groovy:

```
stage('deploy') {
    steps {
        script {

            String serviceURL

            switch(env.BRANCH_NAME)
             case 'master':
             case 'develop':
                serviceURL = "http://myserver:8100/jira/rest/plugins/1.0"
                break
             case ~/^release.*$/:
                serviceURL = "http://myserver:8100/jira/rest/plugins/1.0"
                break
             default:
               throw new Exception( 'Unknown' )
            }

            // Request to get token
            "${serviceURL}?os_authType=basic".toURL().openConnection().with{
              if( 200 != responseCode ) return

              outputStream.withWriter{ it << jsonInputString }
           }
        }
     }
}
```

Here the `withWriter{}` takes care about stream flushing and closing.

Comment: thanks for helping me. I wonder why the error message pointed me to the wrong line number. Ok I did not know groovy does some imports automatically. That is really unusual. Or maybe it is normal for scripting languages like Groovy.

Comment: well, automatic import is "usual" unless you want to make coding unnecessary complicated :)

Comment: aha . I know programming languages like Java or C++. And there you always have to import / include everything. It seems in Jenkins scripting it is not even allowed to have imports. In normal groovy it is allowed though I think

Comment: in jeknins its normal to have imports, but you have to declare them like in java - on the very top of the code

Comment: does groovy have try with resources ??? I get error with this code here:                 try(OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
                    byte[] input = jsonInputString.getBytes("utf-8");
                    os.write(input, 0, input.length);
                }

Comment: in Groovy 3 it's possible, but the proper groovy way is different. See the update in my post

Comment: so I have to get rid of try..with resources and do it the old way. OK I will do that. One more question to imports. Does Groovy only import let's say java.net.URL automatically when it finds out there is a URL class used in the code ?? So does it mean it compiles it and if there are errors it adds the import java.net.URL? But in a file where URL is not used of course it will not import it . Right ?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what the keyword `import` in java means. it does NOT "import" classes, it merely lets you use the class-name only w/o package. W/o import you would have to write `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat( "dd.MM.yy" )`

Comment: ok.  so normal import just gives me right to even use some class . What is the abbreviation W/o package and W/o import ??

Comment: "w/o" == "without"

Comment: if you have time , can you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68039227/why-my-jenkins-pipeline-script-gets-http-status-401-when-trying-to-install-jira